# How to export CoreData database into a file on a Device with the ability to import data from this file?

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, database-backups

In my app, I use CoreData to store the content created by user.

I want the user to be able to tap on a button in menu and Export his Core Data database content to a file on his device (maybe Json, SQlite or any other type of file or Dropbox).

Also I want the user to be able to Import data from this file.

I'm not interested in CloudKit or any other cloud backups, I need a file to be created. This file must have the ability to be shared later or ported to other device.

What is the best way to do this Importing/Exporting (On-Device Backup Feature) nowadays, how can this be done efficiently?

Swift 4, Xcode 9

Comment: It depends on the contents of the entities and their relationships but basically it’s possible with JSON, Property List or NSCoding export.

Comment: did u succeed in this concept?